# PHP: Pass Array to Function with 2 acceptable variable only

Tags: php, arrays

How can i pass the value in my array to a function that can only accept 2 variable.

function i created

```
function sum_the_time($time1,$time2){
    $times = array($time1, $time2);
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
        list($hour,$minute,$second) = explode(':', $time);
        $seconds += $hour*3600;
        $seconds += $minute*60;
        $seconds += $second;
    }

    $hours = floor($seconds/3600);
    $seconds -= $hours*3600;
    $minutes  = floor($seconds/60);
    $seconds -= $minutes*60;
    return sprintf('%02d:%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
}
```

when i try to display it gives me the total time:
here how i display the result.

```
echo sum_the_time('01:45:22', '17:27:03');
```

where i declared the time.

i want to pass the stored value in my array
here's what i did

```
$stored_time = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($lang_val);$i++){
    $target_time = $project_time;
    $stored_time[] = $target_time;
}
```

this will add a value to my array[].
the time is get from the generated script.

i just want to know how can i pass the value of my array. to the function i created.
sometimes there are 3 value in my array or my 5 or so on.

Comment: Can you not change the function's parameters?

Comment: i just want to pass the array value to my function.
example:
$stored_value ['00:15:00','00:15:00','00:15:00'] or sometimes it can only have 2 value.
how can i pass that to my functuion?

Comment: What I meant was you should change your function signature. Instead of it accepting 2 variables, make it accept an array as a parameter. Are you restricted from changing the function by any chance?

Comment: yes, i need that to work.

any way how can i make that function accept a array parameter ?

Comment: That's exactly what the below answers do. Change your function to `function sum_the_time($times)`, remove the second line -> `$times = array(...` and you can call it as `sum_the_time($stored_time)`.

Comment: @RhyManlangit You should accept one of the answers, because seems like your problem is solved. This is how things work here. You can use the tickmark next to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the function and make it accept an array instead.

```
function sum_the_time($times){
    $seconds = 0;
    foreach ($times as $time) {
    //...
```

Answer (score 0):

pass `$times` array directly to the `function sum_the_time()` as

```
$times = array($time1, $time2);
function sum_the_time($times)
{
    if (count($times) > 0)
    {
       // your code
    }
}
```

Comment: how?
all the value are in this array $stored_time; how can i write it?

Comment: create the $stored_time using array_push($stored_time,$target_time); in for loop and pass it to the function